# Remembering last IP from scapy, print without repitition

Tags: python, api, scapy, packet-capture, sniffing

Sorry if this a newbie question, but I've been writing some code to sniff for STUN packets from Omegle (yes I'm aware that it's an invasion of privacy and no I'm not gonna use the data collected for malicious purposes), however while sniffing using scapy, I've noticed it will continually print more and more packets coming from the sniff containing the same IP, and I imagine from the same stream?

I'd like to have it memorize the last IP address it discovered, currently I'm using a crude and hacky method to have it memorize, but it's just not optimal to use.

Code below:

```py
import sys
import requests
import json
from scapy.all import *
from rich.console import Console
from rich.table import Table
from rich import print

# Consistant set of hex bytes during STUN negotiations.
stunxor = ' 01 01 00 2C '
localip = str(sys.argv[1])
console = Console()


def print_summary(pkt):
   try:
       hexpkt = hexstr(pkt, onlyhex=1)
       if hexpkt.find(stunxor) != -1:
           try:
               ip_addr = pkt[IP].src
               file_check = open('last_ip.txt', 'r')
               if ip_addr in file_check.read():
                   pass
               else:
                   with open('last_ip.txt', 'w') as file_check:
                       file_check.write(ip_addr)
                   console.clear()
                   table = Table(title='Current user data')
                   api_data = requests.get("https://ipinfo.io/" + ip_addr + "/geo")
                   api_data_loaded = json.loads(api_data.text)
                   if api_data_loaded is not None:
                       country_code = api_data_loaded['country']
                       city = api_data_loaded['city']
                       subdivision = api_data_loaded['region']
                       table.add_column("IP", style="cyan", no_wrap=True)
                       table.add_column("Country", style="cyan", no_wrap=True)
                       table.add_column("City", style="cyan", no_wrap=True)
                       table.add_column("Subdivison", style="cyan", no_wrap=True)
                       table.add_row(ip_addr, country_code, city, subdivision)
                       console.print(table, justify="center")
           except Exception as e:
               print(e)
   except Exception as e:
       print(e)


try:
   filter = f"src not {localip} and udp and host {localip}"
   sniff(filter=filter, prn=print_summary, iface='Ethernet')
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

Some things to note:

- Lines 21-25 is the hacky method of remembering the last IP, it calls from a local file (which HAS to be there to run properly) which will contain the IP address of the last packet captured with the sniffer under the filter.
- Line 28 is calling to the ipinfo.io API to get location data which outputs in JSON. Example from stackoverflow.com below:

```json
{
  "ip": "151.101.193.69",
  "anycast": true,
  "city": "San Francisco",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.7621,-122.3971",
  "org": "AS54113 Fastly",
  "postal": "94107",
  "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
  "readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"
}
```

Any help is appreciated, if you choose not to help me, I can understand why and I appreciate you reading anyway.

Comment: "*yes I'm aware that it's an invasion of privacy*" Then why would you ever do this? Ethically, this should absolutely be a full stop, end of story.

Comment: My idea of ethical is scare the user into protecting themselves, and this would definitely do it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing a couple things:

- Added a global variable, ip_global, with a initial string (127.0.0.1)
- Removed lines 21-25 and replaced it with the code below:

```py
                if ip_global == ip_addr:
                    pass
                else:
                    ip_global = ip_addr
```

Now works fine it seems.